# Avada Add Space Between Menu Items

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this, if not please point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance. My question is how do I add spaces between the main menu titles? Home, About Us, Prices and Contact Us are close together. When I try to add padding the whole menu moves. I want it to look like the Apple website. I can't find any option under the theme options.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the question is : how do I add spaces between the main menu titles in theme Avada ? 
here is the answer: go to Avada Theme options
[image]

then edit the size you want in Main Menu Item Padding: Controls the right padding for menu text in pixels..

then the before and after effect is like : 
[image]

[image]